# React navigation: stack navigator with tab navigator is not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, native-base

[image]
[image]

We checked other issues and documentation as well but couldn't find any solution that will solve this issue. Here is the code:

It shows error message :

**react children only expected to receive a single react element child.**

```js
   const MainTabBar = TabNavigator(
  {

   Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
   Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},

  },

    {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = 'search';
        } 
         else if (routeName === 'Profile') {
          iconName = 'contact';
        }

        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#222222',
      inactiveTintColor: '#222222',
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    initialRouteName: 'Saved'

  }
);

const Main = StackNavigator(
  {
   Signin: {screen: SigninScreen},
    Signup: {screen: SignupScreen},
    Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
   Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
   Post: {screen: PostScreen},
   MainTab: {screen: MainTabBar}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Signin",
    headerMode: "none",
  },
);
```

How can these 2 navigators Stack navigator and Tab navigator work with each other? At the moment we are trying to navigate from Signin to Home while this.props.navigation.navigate () option is not working. In the past when we used Drawer instead of tab it worked but now it doesn't work with Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
const MainTabBar = TabNavigator(
  {
   Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Chat: {screen: ChatScreen},
    Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
  },
  ...
    // Set initial tab to HomeScreen/Tab
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
    swipeEnabled: false,
  }
);

const Main = StackNavigator(
  {
    Post: {screen: PostScreen},
    Signin: {screen: SigninScreen},
    Signup: {screen: SignupScreen},
    Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
    Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen},
    //Add MainTab as a screen
    MainTab: {screen: MainTabBar}
  },
  ...
);
```

And from your SigninScreen : `this.props.navigation.navigate()` navigate to "MainTab" as the routeName.

Here is a good article to read [React-Navigation : Stack Navigator inside Tab Navigator inside Drawer Navigator](https://codeburst.io/react-native-navigation-stack-navigator-inside-tab-navigator-inside-drawer-navigator-b2f21836708d)

Comment: Thanks for replying :)  However it's not working. I've added updated code with your solution and it shows the errors that I mentioned in the question. What is wrong? I am really confused.

Comment: I have no idea why does it cause such issue.

Comment: I've also added images of these 2 issues It caused after doing the changes that you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue, I found that having both the navigators in same scope(inside a react component) causes this problem.

Ex: This won't work:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const A = ({ navigation }) => {
  const B = (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
  const C = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <Stack.Screen name="Default" component={B} />
        ...
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
  return C;
};

export A;
```

But this will work:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const A = ({ navigation }) => {
  const B = (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
  return B;
};   

const C = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
    <Stack.Screen name="Default" component={A} />
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
);

export C;
```